# libGDX: How to easily change animation speed?

Tags: java, animation, libgdx

I'm using an [AnimationController](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/utils/AnimationController.html) for one of my animations, but I need to vary the speed of this animation very often. I'm looking for any resource-friendly way to do so, perfect would be something like `AnimationController.setSpeed(float speed)`, but sadly that doesn't exist.
So, is there any better way than calling `AinmationController.animate(...)` every time, when I only want to change the speed and all other properties should stay the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the overall speed, simply adjust the delta of the update method accordingly:

```
animationController.update(speed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
```

To change the speed of a single animation (only useful when blending animations), use the AnimationDesc instance the #animate() method returns.

```
AnimationDesc ad = animationController.animate(...);
ad.speed = 0.5f;
```

You can change the AnimationDesc during the animation.

Finally you can also access the current AnimationDesc of the AnimationController, although I wouldn't recommend that:

```
animationController.current.speed = 0.5f;
```

tl;dr: The best method is to use the AnimationController#update(delta) method to change the speed.

See also: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/3D-animations-and-skinning

Answer (score 0):

I'd try extending `AnimationController` to write the `setSpeed` method. Hopefully, animation speed will be stored in a variable that you could just update.